# seperating body content from footer, avoid line break in paragraph content and place the paragraph in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style my page that contains some paragraph. But the paragraph content stays on the left even if I apply text-align as justify. Also I haven't apply any line breaks but it looks like there is some line breaks where I want to spread the content throughout the page with proper mergin. It looks something like this:
[image: paragrah on left with unnessary line breaks]

The end of the paragraph is overlapping with footer. I don't want to change anything about the footer. It's just the body content.
[image: paragraph overlapping with footer]

my css code for body:

```
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #7f8c8d 80%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100vh;
    width:100vh;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
 }

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    color:white;
}

p{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-align: middle;
}
.box-element{
    box-shadow:hsl(0, 2%, 27%) 0 0 16px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
}

.thumbnail{
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 280px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
}

.product{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.bg-dark{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #485461 !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 100%, #7f8c8d 80%) !important;
}

.form-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#cart-icon{
    width:25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top:-60px;
}

#cart-total{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Raleway Bold';
    font-weight: 1000;
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

.col-lg-4, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-12{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}

.btn{
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

.row-image{
    width: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-field{
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cart-row{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
    border-inline-end: 1px;
    padding:40px;

}

.quantity{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right:10px;


}

.chg-quantity{
    width: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transition:.2s;
}

.chg-quantity:hover{
    opacity: .6;
}


.hidden{
    display: none!important;
}
#Login{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#Logout{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
#Search{
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:300px;
    background-color: #000000 0%;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#search-icon{
    width:32px;
    height: 31px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -32px;
    margin-top: 0.3px;
    border-right: 2px;
}
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7f8c8d 80%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left:600px;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
```

main.html code snippets that contain body and footer:

```
    <div class="container" >
        <br>
        {% block content %}


        {% endblock content %}
    </div>

    <section>
        <footer>
            <div class = "footer">
                <div class= "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-bottom" role="navigation">
                    <div class="navbar-text pull-middle">
                        <div class="container">
                            <a href="{% url 'about' %}" style="text-decoration:none;color:White;align-items:center;font-size:15px">About Us<span class="sr-only"> | </span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </footer>
    </section>
```

aboutus.html where Iam mainly facing the above problems:

```
{% extends 'customertemplates/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% for x in writeup %}
<div class="container">    
    <p style="color:white; text-align:justify;">{{x}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Provide more information. Add full code as your question doesn't make sense without seeing the exact code where the problem occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the body height and width to 100% instead of vh, then you can set the width of the paragraph container wrapper to whatever you want, and then use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it. I also notice you have the paragraph styled with a `text-align: middle;`. I don't think that's causing your issue here, but make sure to set it as `text-align: center;` in the future!

```css
body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 0%, #7f8c8d 80%);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
 }

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    color:white;
}

p{
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.box-element{
    box-shadow:hsl(0, 2%, 27%) 0 0 16px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 90%;
}

.thumbnail{
    margin-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 280px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
    box-shadow: -1px -3px 5px -2px rgba(214,214,214,1);
}

.product{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

.bg-dark{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #485461 !important;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000000 100%, #7f8c8d 80%) !important;
}

.form-group{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#cart-icon{
    width:25px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top:-60px;
}

#cart-total{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Raleway Bold';
    font-weight: 1000;
    margin-left: 220px;
    margin-top: -60px;
}

.col-lg-4, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-12{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;

}

.btn{
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: black;
}

.row-image{
    width: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-field{
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.cart-row{
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ececec;
    border-inline-end: 1px;
    padding:40px;

}

.quantity{
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 700;
    padding-right:10px;


}

.chg-quantity{
    width: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    transition:.2s;
}

.chg-quantity:hover{
    opacity: .6;
}


.hidden{
    display: none!important;
}
#Login{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

#Logout{
    margin-left: 70px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: black;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
#Search{
    width: 400px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:300px;
    background-color: #000000 0%;
    border-color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#search-icon{
    width:32px;
    height: 31px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -32px;
    margin-top: 0.3px;
    border-right: 2px;
}
.footer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #7f8c8d 80%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding-left:600px;
    padding-top: 25px;
  }
  
 .p-container-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <br> {% block content %} {% extends 'customertemplates/main.html' %} {% load static %} {% block content %} {% for x in writeup %}
  <div class="p-container-wrapper">
    <p style="color:white; text-align:justify;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime mollitia, molestiae quas vel sint commodi repudiandae consequuntur voluptatum laborum numquam blanditiis harum quisquam eius sed odit fugiat iusto fuga praesentium optio, eaque rerum!
      Provident similique accusantium nemo autem. Veritatis obcaecati tenetur iure eius earum ut molestias architecto voluptate aliquam nihil, eveniet aliquid culpa officia aut! Impedit sit sunt quaerat, odit, tenetur error, harum nesciunt ipsum debitis
      quas aliquid. Reprehenderit, quia. Quo neque error repudiandae fuga? Ipsa laudantium molestias eos sapiente officiis modi at sunt excepturi expedita sint? Sed quibusdam recusandae alias error harum maxime adipisci amet laborum. Perspiciatis minima
      nesciunt dolorem! Officiis iure rerum voluptates a cumque velit quibusdam sed amet tempora. Sit laborum ab, eius fugit doloribus tenetur fugiat, temporibus enim commodi iusto libero magni deleniti quod quam consequuntur! Commodi minima excepturi
      repudiandae velit hic maxime doloremque. Quaerat provident commodi consectetur veniam similique ad earum omnis ipsum saepe, voluptas, hic voluptates pariatur est explicabo fugiat, dolorum eligendi quam cupiditate excepturi mollitia maiores labore
      suscipit quas? Nulla, placeat. Voluptatem quaerat non architecto ab laudantium modi minima sunt esse temporibus sint culpa, recusandae aliquam numquam totam ratione voluptas quod exercitationem fuga. Possimus quis earum veniam quasi aliquam eligendi,
      placeat qui corporis!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<section>
  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div class="navbar-text pull-middle">
          <div class="container">
            <a href="{% url 'about' %}" style="text-decoration:none;color:White;align-items:center;font-size:15px">About Us<span class="sr-only"> | </span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks. setting width to 100% works. But I couldn't set height to 100% as the background does not cover up my page in case of lower content.